# Does android:exported="false" restrict system calls/access?

Tags: android

I know that setting android:exported="false" will restrict other applications from using/accessing my application components.
Does setting this attribute will restrict the system as well from using/accessing my components? i doubt.

for example, i have the following receiver:

```
   <receiver
        android:name="ConnectivityManager"
        android:label="NetworkConnection"
        android:exported = "false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

The receiver is still receiving broadcasts from the system once the connection state changes (on/of).

Does this mean that the system calls/access can never be stopped? Please illustrate.

Comment: You receive the broadcast ONLY if you actively request to receive it. If you don't want it, why don't you call the `unregisterReceiver()` method?

Comment: Yes, you are right for the second questions i asked. I can either setComponentEnabledSetting() or unregisterReceiver() to disable/kill the receiver. But my main concern is "Does android:exported=“false” restrict system calls/access?".

Answer (score 5):

Google‘s online document does not describe this clearly.

From the real result, the receiver can still be triggered by system broadcast even if set exported="false".

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if exported="false", it will still respond to system broadcasts such as connectivity changes. This is easy to test by using your above broadcast-receiver and toggling airplane mode