# Sync adapter service exported but unprotected

Tags: android

*Fellow Developers!*

I have a sync adapter in my app and a corresponding sync service. I have declared everything, including the sync service, according to [Google example code](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html#DeclareSyncAdapterManifest). The greater picture looks something like this:

```
<service
    android:name="com.myapp.SyncService"
    android:exported="true"
    android:process=":sync">

    <intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"/>
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
        android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />

</service>
```

While it makes sense to set the `android:exported` attribute to `true` on the service (enabling the Android system to reach it), I'm a bit puzzled on how to tie it down in terms of access rights. I don't want anyone else but my app and the Android system to have access to the service.

Maybe a bit naively I have created my own permission for this:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.myapp.permission.SYNC_ADAPTER"
    android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem" />
```

But reading up a bit on the `protectionLevel` makes me wonder even more. [Google says](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html#plevel):

> Please avoid using this option [...] "signatureOrSystem" permission is used for certain special situations where multiple vendors have applications built into a system image and need to share specific features explicitly because they are being built together.

The described scenario is far from my use case. The question then remains:

***How do I secure my sync service so that the Android system, but no third party apps, can access it?***

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to use just a "signature" protectionLevel? I suspect system will still be able to access your sync adapter.

Comment: Yes, I have. And exactly as you mention, the Android system *seems* to have access. But is this a documented behavior? Am I lucky on my device? Will all users of my app be lucky on their devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is a SyncAdapter permission. I'm guessing that we can safely ignore the error. See the bug filed here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37280

Comment: it's recommended to add the signature permission see @beworker's comment

Answer (score 3):

[beworker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1219199/beworker) is quite right. I have used signature permission and the system is able to sync without any trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely set `exported=false` for both services

- one service registering to the `SyncAdapter`
- one service registering to the `AccountAuthenticator` intents

The system [can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354012/does-androidexported-false-restrict-system-calls-access) still call the `SyncAdapter` Service via intents.

- The reason why this works is mentioned in the official `exported`  [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported)

> If `false`, the activity can be launched ... [by] privileged system components.

I.e. you don't need to struggle with exported=true.

- tested on Android 10 (Emulator with `targetVersion: 30`)
- tested on Android 13 (with `targetVersion: 31`)

---

**Old answer**

*The following is (for me) irrelevant as the above works.*

I interpreted the replies in this thread this way:

- Requesting this permission (see example) in an `exported` service (see below) should only allow apps signed with your signature - and the system - to call this service.
- If you use `exported=false` then the system cannot call your service, i.e. Synchronization won't start if your app is closed(?)

```
    <permission
        android:name="com.myapp.USE_SYNC_AND_AUTHENTICATOR"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <application>
        <!-- Export sync and auth to allow the Android System to call them. -->
        <!-- Protect it using a signature permission.  -->
        <service
            android:name="com.myapp.SyncService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":sync"
            android:permission="com.myapp.USE_SYNC_AND_AUTHENTICATOR">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                    android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                    android:resource="@xml/sync_adapter" />
        </service>
        <service>..authenticator..</service>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Looking at this example source code here as a guide https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Exchange/+/ics-mr0/AndroidManifest.xml  it seems to be that the sync adapters have plainly exported="true" without any permissions.

Comment: Yes, I have also observed that none of the online examples seem to have any elaborative discussion on the security (permissions) aspect. When I come to the point that I put my code onto the test bench (Jenkins) I get explicit lint warnings as well, basically telling me what I already know; that I have a wide open door here :-)

Answer (score 0):

The 'signature' protection level should be sufficient for your use case, which grants access to the system package. 'signatureOrSystem' also grants access to apps built into the system image.

Source code: see `grantSignaturePermission()` method
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a029ea1/services/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java